# Unable to activate a specific anaconda environment

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, anaconda

I am trying to activate a python environment but when i check which python, it doesn't reflect the change. And this happens only for one particular environment. Example follows.

```
(datasc) vincent (master) scripts $ conda info --env
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/vincent/anaconda3
code-buf                 /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/code-buf
datasc                *  /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/datasc
dato-env                 /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/dato-env
django                   /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/django
gql_extraction_py        /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/gql_extraction_py
new_gql                  /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/new_gql
py2datasc                /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/py2datasc
python_2_expt            /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/python_2_expt
web-dev                  /home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/web-dev

(datasc) vincent (master) scripts $ which python
/home/vincent/anaconda3/bin/python

(datasc) vincent (master) scripts $ conda activate
(base) vincent (master) scripts $ which python
/home/vincent/anaconda3/bin/python

(base) vincent (master) scripts $ conda activate code-buf
(code-buf) vincent (master) scripts $ which python
/home/vincent/anaconda3/envs/code-buf/bin/python

(code-buf) vincent (master) scripts $ conda activate datasc
(datasc) vincent (master) scripts $ which python
/home/vincent/anaconda3/bin/python
```

As a consequence, imports are failing since the package it's looking for doesn't existin the base environment.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well. No responses so far.
A workaround for now appears to be:

```
conda deactivate
conda activate datasc
```

which python now returns the envs python. So I guess that works for now.